# IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred in google play services game android project

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I am using google play services game,

using link **https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples**

But I am  facing some problems in enter app-id. in that app-id must be numeric but i have a numeric-string mix app id creating `using console.google.developer`, like **123-30abcd.apps.googleusercontent.com** .

So how can I use app-id in my project.I assume that this is reason of my error  **IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred**

so please help me to solve it  .

Comment: please any one know about it,give answers

Answer (score 1):

Your APP ID is made up of digits only. The format is something like 123456789012. What you are trying to use is the CLIENT ID, which is a different thing, and is not used in Android at all. Go to the [developer console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) and click to open your game entry. Now look at the top part of that page, where it shows your game's icon and name. You will see a 12-digit number there, to the right of your game's name. That is your APP ID!

Comment: i not put this project/app into the market, i just run it before put on market.

Comment: so,it required to first register this game app in developer console ? if we not include any client id,then it where to store game status ?

Comment: where to store save game data ?

Comment: Before it i develop one app about  google cloud save in that i save my android app data into the google cloud save after creating project in https://console.developers.google.com/  in that i register client id,web client id etc in my app and it done successfully and store data on google cloud on base of that i used this example to save data using google play game services and i stop here so my question is that in case of this where we store data ?if we not register with it